# display images side by side

Tags: css

I am trying to display 2 arrow links side by side but am getting some css errors.

My html code is below:

```
 <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_down"> <span class="down_arrow">&nbsp;</span> </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_up">  <span class="up_arrow">&nbsp;</span></a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.down_arrow{
display:block;
background: url(../images/down_arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
}

.up_arrow{
display:block;
background: url(../images/up_arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Currently, the images are displayed one below another. I want then to be displayed side by side.
However if i remove the `display:block;` in the css, the image is not displayed properly.

I also tried removing the display:block and put float:left for both classes  but still not working.

I would be grateful if someone could provide me with a solution.

Many many thanks.

Comment: How is it not displayed properly when you remove the display:block? What happens?

Comment: Only part of the image is displayed,..the image isn't displayed completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the images float you have to specify a width of the element and set the `float` property. The CSS must look like this

```
.down_arrow{
display:block;
background: url(../images/down_arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
float:left;
width:100px;
}

.up_arrow{
display:block;
background: url(../images/up_arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
float:left;
width:100px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fq3Eg/ for your example, I adjusted the CSS and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually remove the SPAN tags and do something like this...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/juGME/1

Demo 2: (with arrow images): http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/juGME/2/

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_down" class="down_arrow"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="move_up" class="up_arrow"></a>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#move_down, #move_up {
    float: left; 
}
.down_arrow, .up_arrow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.down_arrow {
    background-image: url(path/to/img);
}
.up_arrow {
    background-image: url(path/to/img);
}
```

Comment: the images are not completely displayed, i can only see the tip of the arrows--although they are now displayed side by side

Comment: do i need to indicate somewhere the width and height of the image?

Comment: Yes, try setting the width/height on the span, since it's a background image.