# How do I have two photos stay next to eachother in HTML?

Tags: html

I keep trying to put two photos together for my website, but everytime I do it wraps the text below it in weird ways. Even when I tried to separate the photos and text with 
 it still happened. I tried looking it up only and it told me to try using align, but when I did that the photos would sometimes block the text depending on the size of the screen.

Comment: add html code so people can help you 

Comment: This is likely a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253466/display-images-side-by-side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display images side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253466/display-images-side-by-side)